# Limit Comparison Test with $\ln\left(\frac{n^2}{n^2-1} \right)$ and $\frac{1}{n^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

Determine whether $\sum_{n=8}^\infty$ $\ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{n^2-1} \right)$ converges and find the sum if so.

I know that it converges and Ive found the sum using telescoping form. But I'm having trouble proving convergence. Simply comparing it directly to 1/n^2 is not enough so I was recommended to use the Limit Comparison Test. Which leaves me with 
$\lim_{n\to \infty} \ln\left(\frac{n^2}{n^2-1} \right)*n^2 $ I am lost as to how to simplify this limit so that I can perform L'hopital on it..

Comment: If you already proved that $$\sum_{n=2}^{N}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2-1}\right)=\log\frac{2N}{N+1}$$ then convergence is trivial (just let $N\to +\infty$).

Comment: I dont follow....

Comment: If you have a closed expression for the partial sums, what is difficult in proving that the series is converging? In the previous case, $$\sum_{n\geq 2}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2-1}\right) = \lim_{N\to +\infty}\log\frac{2N}{N+1}=\log(2).$$ Your actual series starts at $n=8$ but that is no big difference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Use $0 \le \log(1+x) \le x$ ,and the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^2-1}= \dfrac{1}{2}\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(\dfrac{1}{n-1}-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)= \dfrac{1}{2}\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(\dfrac{1}{n-1}-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)+\dfrac{1}{2}\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(\dfrac{1}{n} - \dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)$, each of which is summable to a finite real value. As for using the limit comparison test that you've done some of it. What is left is to prove:

$\displaystyle L = \lim_{n\to \infty} n^2\cdot \ln\left(\dfrac{n^2}{n^2-1}\right)= \text{non-zero real constant}$. To this end, put $m = n^2$, then $L = \displaystyle \lim_{m \to \infty} m\cdot \ln\left(\dfrac{m}{m-1}\right) = \displaystyle \lim_{m \to \infty} \dfrac{\ln\left(\dfrac{m}{m-1}\right)}{\dfrac{1}{m}}= \displaystyle \lim_{m\to \infty} \dfrac{m}{m-1} = 1$ by L
hospitale's formula.

Comment: I would like to use the limit comparison test. I am not able to take for granted that ln(1+x) < x so I would have to give the proof for that as well..

Comment: @TatianaFrank: See my edited post.